# How to retrieve a variable from postback and use it in JsonQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would like to know how should I write the code for sending the name of the button to other page and with this value make another jquery?...

The first step I think is correct....I've set the linkButton properties as this

```
linkButt.Postback = "./page2.aspx";
linkButt.CommandName = "carMakeName";
```

and than when the linkButton is clicked, I try to retrieve the variable in the pageload of page2.aspx writing this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string carMakeName= Request.Form.Get("carMakeName");
        }
```

I'm not sure which is the right way....I hope that someone can help me.

Thank you!!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `Page_Load` and check what's in `sender`. You might find something interesting there.

Comment: I was checking the sender contenent and I couldn't see the linkButt.CommandName's value that i'd set previously...help please! :)

Comment: What was the content of `sender`?

Comment: `base {WebApplication1.WebSite.pg3}: {ASP.WebSite_pg3_aspx}
ApplicationInstance: {ASP.global_asax}
Profile: {System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile}`

Only this....and inside this 3 type nothing about the linkButt that i've clicked before to arrive in this page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreviousPage` property to get previous page's controls as you do cross page post-back. Try this in your `page2.aspx Page_Load`:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    LinkButton lnkBtn = 
        (LinkButton)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("LinkButton1");
    if (lnkBtn != null)
    {
        string carMakeName = lnkBtn.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank u, really!!
I gave an Exception on the first line of your code

_Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error executing child request for handler 'ASP.WebSite_pg2_aspx'._

Maybe the problem is because pg2.aspx is a iFrame and for this reason pg3.aspx can't retrive the PreviousPage...

Comment: What do in that case?....and once resolved this problem how can insert string carMakeName in jquery and use it in this way: $(function () {$.getJSON("http://www...com/api/0.3/?callback=?", { cmd: "getModel", make:` **??? string carMakeName ???** `}, function (data) { var models = $.map(data.Models, function (model) { return model.model_display; }).join(";"); document.getElementById("<%= CarModelsHiddenField.ClientID %>").value = models; __doPostBack("<%= CarModelsUpdatePanel.ClientID %>", "./pg4.aspx"); }); });

Comment: What is its html markup? You can write carMakeName value in a javascript variable or any input hidden field by using Page.RegisterStartupScript() from there you can include it in your json request. Try this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1138565.aspx/1.